# T-SQL EXEC command inside transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I need to execute a store procedure from another with the common `EXEC` command.
I need to be sure, that all the sql statements will be under transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY   

    SET @Esercizio = (SELECT ESERCIZIO_OBIETTIVI_CONSUNTIVARE from TB_SCHEDE WHERE MATRICOLA = @iMATRICOLA and COD_VALUTAZIONE = @iCOD_VALUTAZIONE)
    SET @TipoProcesso = (SELECT ISNULL(TipoProcesso, 'middle') from TB_SCHEDE WHERE MATRICOLA = @iMATRICOLA and COD_VALUTAZIONE = @iCOD_VALUTAZIONE)

    DELETE FROM TB_SCHEDE WHERE MATRICOLA = @iMATRICOLA and COD_VALUTAZIONE = @iCOD_VALUTAZIONE
    DELETE FROM TB_SCHEDE_AUTOVAL WHERE MATRICOLA = @iMATRICOLA and COD_VALUTAZIONE = @iCOD_VALUTAZIONE
    DELETE FROM TB_OBIETTIVI WHERE MATRICOLA = @iMATRICOLA and ESERCIZIO =  @Esercizio
    DELETE FROM TB_OBIETTIVI_AUTOVAL WHERE MATRICOLA = @iMATRICOLA and ESERCIZIO =  @Esercizio

    EXEC AnotherStore @iCOD_VALUTAZIONE, @iMATRICOLA, @TipoProcesso
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

If the `AnotherStore` procedure throw an exception, does the DB engine ensure rollback from the caller store procedure?

Hope to be clear.

Comment: What ever you write under and begin Transaction and rollback transaction will be included as a part of transaction

Comment: Your try catch will catch exception from other stored procedures, yes.

Comment: Shouldn't your begin transaction be included in the begin try block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for an example of execption handling in the presence of transactions:

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes it will rollback the changes for the caller stored procedure, but think it through if you have transactions inside the other stored procedure, there are possibilities for things not behaving as you expect if that is the case.  A `ROLLBACK` will affect ALL of the transactions, although this is probably what you want.  You can use `@@TRANCOUNT` within your catch and determine if you want to rollback the entire thing, and [Savepoints.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378414%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Everything you do *to the database* between the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`or `ROLLBACK` is part of the transaction, and if any lines get an error, control will be routed to the `CATCH` block where the transaction will be rolled back.  *Things like table variables would fall outside of this scope and not get rolled back*.    And as @David Brabant said, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` should be in the `BEGIN TRY` block.